# Is SQL Login the only Azure Data Migration Service (DMS) target database Authentication Type?

Tags: azure, data-migration

When setting up a Data Migration Project, migrating from SQL database to Azure SQL Database in Azure Portal, I can only see the option to connect to the Target database using SQL Login Authentication Type.

I expect to see more options - like Azure AD integrated Mode.
I am in Azure AD Group assigned as SQL Admin on the Azure SQL Server.

Is any other Authentication Type supported for the target Azure Server?

If others are support, what do I need to do to get them to be available in the Authentication Option for the target server?

Thank you

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The following tutorial spells out that only SQL Logins are currently supported:
https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/dms/tutorial-sql-server-to-azure-sql#specify-target-details

[image]